# Trying to write a loop that uses an OutputStream to write to a text file

Tags: java, text, outputstream, writer

I'm not a java programmer, I'm a VB programmer.  I am doing this as part of an assignment, however, I'm not asking for help on something assignment related.  I'd like to figure out how to get the `OutputStreamWriter` to work properly in this instance.  I just want to capture the values I'm generating and place them into a text document.  The file is generated, but only one entry exists, not the 40 I'm expecting.  I could do this in a heartbeat with VB, but java feels very strange to me right now.  Your help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Steve

Here's the code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start, end;
    double result,difference;

    try {
      //OutputStream code assistance from 
      // http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/outputstreamwriter.html
      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("c:\\Temp\\output1.txt");
      Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);

      for(int n=1; n<=20; n++) {
        //Calculate the Time for n^2.
        start = System.nanoTime();

        //Add code to call method to calculate n^2
        result =  mN2(n);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        difference = (end - start);

        //Output results to a file
        out.write("N^2 End time: " + end + " Difference: " + 
            difference + "\n");
        out.close();
      }
    } catch (IOException e){
    }

    try {
      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("c:\\Temp\\output1.txt");
      Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);

      for(int n=1; n<=20; n++){
        //Calculate the Time for 2^n.
        start = System.nanoTime();
        //Add code to call method to calculate 2^n
        result =  m2N(n);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        difference = (end - start);
        //Output results to a file
        out.write("N^2 End time: " + end + " Difference: " + difference + "\n");
        out.close();
      }
    } catch (IOException e){
    }
  }

  //Calculate N^2
  public static double mN2(double n) {
    n = n*n;
    return n;
  }

  //Calculate 2N
  public static double m2N(double n) {
    n = 2*n;
    return n;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're closing your file within the loop. The next time around the loop you will attempt to write to the closed file, which will throw an exception...but where you catch `IOException` you have an empty block, which will effectively ignore the exception.

Trying moving the `out.close()` call into a `finally` block, like this:

```
try {
  ...
}
catch ( IOException e) {
  // Log any errors
}
finally {
  out.close();
}
```